# domain validation regex without www. and subdomains

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex code to validate domain names :

```
/^(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-æøå]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]$/isu
```

For example It validates :

`domain.tld`
and
`www.domain.tld`

I want to remove `www.domain.tld` and `sub.domain.tld` validation

which part of my code causes the problem?

Comment: @Olivier No those codes not fit my case and have problems

Comment: You didn't say what "your case" is, and which "problems" the linked page has.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Do you want to exclude just "www" or any subdomain ? Do you consider ```sub.domain.tld``` a valid domain ? Relying on a heavy regex to validate domains is cumbersome imo (there are tlds with dots like ```.com.tr``` and long ones like ```.photography```). I would split the domain string at the occurrence of the first dot. I would use a basic regex to validate the first part, and a second basic regex to validate the tld. This will be more readable/maintainable than a single regex accounting growing exceptions and singularities.

Comment: @Musa A small correction in terminology: the TLD of "something.com.tr" is still just "tr" - that's the "top level" in the hierarchy. What you're describing there is usually called a "public suffix", and is a commercial not a technical concept. No text manipulation will ever reliably determine those (e.g. the public suffix of "hello.example.com" is ".com", but for "example.uk.com", it's ".uk.com"), you have to match against a list such as this one: https://publicsuffix.org/

Comment: @IMSoP I think your example was thinking of `co.uk`, not `uk.com`, because in your terminology, the public suffix of `example.uk.com` is `.com`, on the other hand for the - historic - `example.co.uk`, it would be `.co.uk`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel No, it was a deliberately chosen example. Somebody bought "uk.com" (and a bunch of other two-letter domains) and marketed domains under it to businessrs as an alternative to "co.uk". Consequently, browsers *must not* let the owner of "example.uk.com" set a cookie for "uk.com", even though a website at "uk.example.com" *could* set a cookie for "example.com". That's why there's no shortcut to using a well-researched list, there will be dozens of special cases you've never heard of.